# JQuery Mobile CSS not showing Icons in some mobile screens

Tags: jquery, css, mobile

we have a mobile app created with Cordova+PhoneGap. For some reason icons are not being displayed in some screen sizes.

```
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'">
<meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
<meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no">
<meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width">


<access origin="*" />
<!-- Tell the browser to be responsive to screen width -->
<meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no" name="viewport">

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/themes/jquery.mobile.flatui.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="lib/datatables/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="lib/datatables/css/responsive.dataTables.min.css">

<script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>

<style type="text/css">


    table.dataTable.display tbody tr.bills {
    background-color: #ff6666;
    color: white ;
    }

    table.dataTable.display tbody tr.co {
    background-color: seagreen;
    color: white ;
    }

    .responsiveImg{
                width: 100%;
                height: 100%;
                min-width: 0%;
                min-height: 0%;
                max-width: 100%;
                max-height: 100%;
            }

</style>



<div data-role="page" data-theme="a" id="pageLoading">
<div data-role="header">
    <h1>Loading...</h1>
</div>
<div data-role="main">
    <div class="ui-content">


    </div>
</div>

</div>
<div data-role="page" data-theme="a" id="login">
<div data-role="header">
    <h1>Login</h1>
</div>
<div data-role="main">
    <div class="ui-content">
        <form id="login-form" >

            <label for="user">Usuario:</label>
            <input type="text" name="user" id="user" value="">

            <label for="pass">Contraseña:</label>
            <input type="password" name="pass" id="pass" value="">

            <input type="hidden" name="phonekey" id="phonekey" value="">

            <input id="btnLogin" type="button" value="Ingresar"  data-theme="b">

        </form>


    </div>
</div>
<div data-role="footer">
    <div class="ui-content footerName">
        TITLE
    </div>
</div>
</div>

<div data-role="page" data-theme="a" id="home">
<div data-role="header">
    <h1>Home</h1>
</div>
<div data-role="main">
    <div class="ui-content">
        <div>
            <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" id="main_menu">
                <li data-icon="user"><a href="#my_data" data-transition="slide">Mis Datos</a></li>
                <li data-icon="bars" id="li_facturas"><a href="#page_bills" data-transition="slide">Mis Facturas</a></li>
                <li data-icon="comment" id="li_tickets"><a href="#page_tickets" data-transition="slide">Mis Tickets</a></li>
```

Now you can see in attached pictures that testing in one emulated screen seems to be fine but in others icons doesn't appear!

[Icons OK](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c6zqF.png)
[Icons Missing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q6V5G.png)

Comment: please provide more details. In which emulators it is not working? How have you added the icons. Have you tired using SVG. Have you tried using FontAwesome?

Comment: as is coded I'm using..<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/themes/jquery.mobile.flatui.min.css">... I tested on my LG mobile, then in a Samsung A5, then I tested (runs ok) on huawei (dont remember the model) and finally in two virtual devices.. (see the picture you can see the model on picture title)

Comment: please create a codepen so we can try it on mobile devices. Also share the URL of the emulator that you are using. Until I see what the error is, I wont be able to help you out. Probably it has something to do with Chrome version. If it is working on one device, it should work on other device.